# What is assembler, in the context of in system programming?

Tags: assembly, systems-programming

What is "assembler" in the context of system programming? What is the difference between "one-pass" and "two-pass" assembler? I'm looking for a detailed explanation.

Comment: I have googled but not found all information in detail and its not h/w question

Comment: @user1640480, Please read a book "System Software by Dhamdhere". It explains everything in a better way.

http://books.google.co.in/books?id=s7zgF7InxIgC&pg=PR11&lpg=PR11&dq=system+software+by+dhamdhere&source=bl&ots=a_68zJoyvk&sig=2Uk8sPDmzkVUMueFDcpaxHZwSz4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ptP8UOX8BsaPrge1hoGgCA&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=system%20software%20by%20dhamdhere&f=false

Answer (score 2):

Assembly is the lowest level programming language a human can still use, that is, it is transliterated into binary, every single instruction has a literal parallel with binary, there is no interpretation in the process, only replacing symbols to binary instructions of a certain amount of bits.

Two pass assembler goes through the entire code twice: first to gather all the symbols and create a table matching symbols to addresses, then a second time to replace the symbols with the addresses (linking process). This allows you to define things wherever you want, since the compiler will first look around all the code for definitions and then look around for uses of definitions.

One-pass assembler goes through the code a single time, trying to do the entire process at once, this is, link files and definitions to labels as it reads a single time. Here it is important to keep the order right, this is, if you don't do this, it won't work at all, because it won't find a symbol you define after you attempt to use it.

Of course the first approach is more natural, but takes twice as long. With slow old computers this was a huge overhead, so it was preferred to go through the code once to the commodity of being able to define symbols anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

These are the system programs which will automatically translate the Assembly Language program compatible with M/CA,in to the machine language program compatible with M/CA,but the underlying M/CS